# PL/SQL to TSQL conversion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, case, data-conversion

I have used a tool to convert PL/SQL to TSQL but I am getting weird errors for some cases.

```
CREATE PROC Dates
(
    @PeriodType varchar(15),
    @ReportStart varchar(15),
    @ReportEnd varchar(15)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE
               WHEN @PeriodType  = 'CUR_WEEK' THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE() + 1 - CONVERT(NUMERIC(8, 2), CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE())), 112))
               WHEN @PeriodType  = 'NEXT_WEEK' THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE() + 8 - CONVERT(NUMERIC(8, 2), CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE())), 112))
               WHEN @PeriodType  = 'PREV_DAY' THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE() - 1, 112))
               WHEN @PeriodType  = 'PREV_WEEK' THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE() - 6 - CONVERT(NUMERIC(8, 2), CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE())), 112))
               WHEN @PeriodType  = 'PREV_2WEEK' THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE() - 13, 112))
               WHEN @PeriodType  = 'CUR_MONTH' THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '01', 112)
               WHEN @PeriodType  = 'DATE_RANGE' THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @ReportStart)
           END AS "StartDate",
           CASE
               WHEN @PeriodType  = 'CUR_WEEK' THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE() + 8 - CONVERT(NUMERIC(8, 2), CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE())), 112)) - (1 / CONVERT(FLOAT, 86400))
               WHEN @PeriodType  = 'NEXT_WEEK' THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE() + 15 - CONVERT(NUMERIC(8, 2), CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE())), 112)) - (1 / CONVERT(FLOAT, 86400))
               WHEN @PeriodType  = 'PREV_DAY' THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)) - (1 / CONVERT(FLOAT, 86400))
               WHEN @PeriodType  = 'PREV_WEEK' THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE() - CONVERT(NUMERIC(8, 2), CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE())), 112)) + 1 - (1 / CONVERT(FLOAT, 86400))
               WHEN @PeriodType  = 'PREV_2WEEK' THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE() + 1, 112)) - (1 / CONVERT(FLOAT, 86400))
               WHEN @PeriodType  = 'CUR_MONTH' THEN DATEADD(M, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)) - (CONVERT(NUMERIC(8, 2), DATEPART(DD, GETDATE())) - 1)) - 1
               WHEN @PeriodType  = 'DATE_RANGE' THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @ReportEnd) + 1
           END AS "EndDate"
END
```

My stored proc is executing for PREV_DAY and PREV_2WEEK for the remaining period type I am getting conversions errors.

```
exec proc Dates 'PREV_DAY','',''
exec proc Dates 'PREV_2WEEK','',''
```

My PL\SQL code is

```
 SELECT CASE 
            WHEN :PeriodType = 'CUR_WEEK'
                 THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1 - TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D')))
            WHEN :PeriodType = 'NEXT_WEEK'
                 THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE + 8 - TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D')))
            WHEN :PeriodType = 'PREV_DAY'
                 THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1)
            WHEN :PeriodType = 'PREV_WEEK'
                 THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 6 - TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D')))
            WHEN :PeriodType = 'PREV_2WEEK'
                 THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 13)
            WHEN :PeriodType = 'CUR_MONTH'
                 THEN to_date(to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMM') || '01','YYYYMMDD')
            WHEN :PeriodType = 'DATE_RANGE'
                 THEN TO_DATE(:ReportStart)
        END  AS "StartDate",
        CASE
            WHEN :PeriodType = 'CUR_WEEK'
                 THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE + 8 - TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D'))) - (1/86400)
            WHEN :PeriodType = 'NEXT_WEEK'
                 THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE + 15 - TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D'))) - (1/86400)
            WHEN :PeriodType = 'PREV_DAY'
                 THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE)-(1/86400)
            WHEN :PeriodType = 'PREV_WEEK'
                 THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D'))) + 1 - (1/86400)
            WHEN :PeriodType = 'PREV_2WEEK'
                 THEN TRUNC ( SYSDATE+1) - (1/86400)
            WHEN :PeriodType = 'CUR_MONTH'
                 THEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD')) - 1), 1) -1
            WHEN :PeriodType = 'DATE_RANGE'
                 THEN TO_DATE(:ReportEnd)+1
        END AS "EndDate"
   FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle and SQLServer work with datetime in different manner.

The tool converted the script as well as a string parser can, like someone translating a quote word by word between two languages.

In SQLServer to work with that data type you have to use the functions `DATEADD`, `DATEDIFF` and other ones that can be found on the [help page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) from MS.

Using the date function of SQLServer the original function translate to

```
CREATE PROC Dates(
@PeriodType varchar(15),
@ReportStart varchar(15),
@ReportEnd varchar(15)
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT CASE WHEN @PeriodType = 'CUR_WEEK' THEN DATEADD(DAY, - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + 1, cast(cast(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime))
              WHEN @PeriodType = 'NEXT_WEEK' THEN DATEADD(DAY, 8 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), cast(cast(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime))
              WHEN @PeriodType = 'PREV_DAY' THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, cast(cast(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime))
              WHEN @PeriodType = 'PREV_WEEK' THEN DATEADD(DAY, - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) - 6, cast(cast(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime))
              WHEN @PeriodType = 'PREV_2WEEK' THEN DATEADD(DAY, - 13, cast(cast(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime))
              WHEN @PeriodType = 'CUR_MONTH' THEN DATEADD(DAY, - DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) + 1, cast(cast(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime))
              WHEN @PeriodType = 'DATE_RANGE' THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @ReportStart)
         END AS StartDate,
       , CASE WHEN @PeriodType = 'CUR_WEEK' THEN DATEADD(mi, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 8 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), cast(cast(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime)))
              WHEN @PeriodType = 'NEXT_WEEK' THEN DATEADD(mi, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 15 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), cast(cast(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime)))
              WHEN @PeriodType = 'PREV_DAY' THEN DATEADD(mi, -1,  DATEADD(DAY, - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + 1, cast(cast(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime)))
              WHEN @PeriodType = 'PREV_WEEK' THEN DATEADD(mi, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 8 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), cast(cast(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime)))
              WHEN @PeriodType = 'PREV_2WEEK' THEN DATEADD(mi, -1, cast(cast(dateadd(DAY, 1, GETDATE()) AS date) AS datetime))
              WHEN @PeriodType = 'CUR_MONTH' THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, cast(cast(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime))+1,0))
              WHEN @PeriodType = 'DATE_RANGE' THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @ReportEnd) + 1
         END AS EndDate
END
```

The double `CAST` in `CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)` is a little hack to get midnight of today, as `GETDATE()` is of datetime type and returns the current date **and time**.

Answer (score 3):

At least one problem is this expression in the first `then` clause:

```
CONVERT(NUMERIC(8, 2), CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE()))
```

This expression:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE())
```

just returned:

```
May 23 2014 3:01AM
```

And that just won't convert to numeric.

I think you need to go through the code line by line to figure out the best way to do things.  Also, whenever you use `varchar` or `char`, you should have a length associated with them.  The default is sometimes (but not always) 1, and that can cause problems.